# SSL certificate for Blogger on a custom sub-domain

Tags: https, security-certificate, blogger

I have Blogspot blog show casing my products running for many years on http:// which is running as `http://products.example.com` for many years.

My DNS record for `example.com` (which I own) at the domain registrar is redirected to my hosting provider (Linux + Cpanel) where the main website is working fine under `https://example.com` with free ssl certificates auto-renewed by Cpanel from LetsEncrypt under a wildcard `*.example.com` which lists about 10 sub-domains under it.

The DNS for `products.example.com` is setup in Cpanel's DNS Zone Editor to point to Google hosting `ghs.googlehosted.com` with a CNAME and also has another security verification CNAME provide by blogger.

Everything works fine under `http://products.example.com` , but Blogger setting for custom domain does not recognise (detect ?) or provide HTTPS on `products.example.com` and when I try to set an SSL certificate on my hosting provider's CPANEL for `products.example.com` is says I don't control this domain.
I tried creating a sub-domain for `products.example.com` in my CPanel but it says the DNS entry already exists.

I need help for setting HTTPS (or HTTPS redirection) to work for `http://products.example.com` which is at blogger and my initial queries are:

1. Does HTTPS work for Blogger blogs operating under a custom sub-domain?
2. Does the HTTPS functionality have to be installed at Blogger or at my hosting provider or both? If so how to go about it?

Comment: HTTPS functionality needs to be installed on your webserver.   (I don't have specific knowledge of blospot as to how they implement this).  A work-arround could be to use a service like cloudflare to terminate HTTPS and get the site over http, but likely there are issues with your DNS config in CPANEL that can be corrected to solve your issues.

Comment: thanks @davidgo
Just to clarify, by "your webserver" do you mean the hosting provider where my entire DNS is redirected by my domain registrar and where I can access the CPANEL ?

Comment: Grossly simplifying - By Web server I mean the software which whose job it is to serve web pages. This means you can't generate a certificate in CPANEL to secure your BLOGSPOT account.   **The HTTPS certificate needs to be generated and installed on the BLOGSPOT server** - Have you tried following https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6284029?hl=en

Comment: Yeah as davidgo says, you just need to manually enable https from within your blogger/blogspot control panel. It's not enabled by default for custom domains, in case there's other configuration requirements, but for most domains you'll be able to just enable it.